# In wordpress admin prevent scripts in title while adding a new page

Tags: php, wordpress

I found that while creating new pages in admin if I enter

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

in the title field and publish/preview the page then the script is getting executed. It clearly shows that the data has not been escaped properly and thus open to xss attacks.

Can anyone please help me out how to sanitize the data before saving in admin section or if there are any plugins as I am fairly new to wordpress. I know a lot of plugins working fine for front-end comments etc but could not find one for admin section.

Answer (score 3):

Setting

```
define( 'DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML', true );
```

in `wp-config.php` is the recommended way to prevent all users from being able in insert scripts in the title and body of posts and pages.

This will remove filter any `<script>` tags out of the fields before saving to the database.

> **Why are some users allowed to post unfiltered HTML?**
>
> Users with Administrator or Editor roles are allowed to publish unfiltered HTML in post titles, post content, and comments. WordPress is, after all, a publishing tool, and people need to be able to include whatever markup they need to communicate. Users with lesser privileges are not allowed to post unfiltered content.
>
> If you are running security tests against WordPress, use a lesser privileged user so that all content is filtered. If you are concerned about an Administrator putting XSS into content and stealing cookies, note that all cookies are marked for HTTP only delivery, and are divided into privileged cookies used for admin pages, and unprivileged cookies used for public facing pages. Content is never displayed unfiltered in the admin. Regardless, an Administrator has wide-ranging super powers, among which unfiltered HTML is a lesser one.
>
> In WordPress Multisite, only the Super Admin can publish unfiltered HTML, as all other users are considered untrusted.
>
> To disable unfiltered HTML for all users, including administrators, you can add `define( 'DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML', true );` to `wp-config.php`.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-security-vulnerabilities/#why-are-some-users-allowed-to-post-unfiltered-html

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of sanitize functions in wordpress , for example :

```
sanitize_title( $title, $fallback_title, $context );
```

Since I do not really know what data or data type you want to sanitize , I can not really choose the right function for you ..

Read more here :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title

and here for a list of other function :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title#Related

Comment: Can you please tell me the page name where data is being saved so that I can use such functions before saving to database. I am talking about admin as the issue is in back-end while creating pages.